# pagination pages not centering

Tags: html, css, pagination

I've been trying to get my pagination 'PAGES' to center within the div that it's in regardless of how big the size of it is. I'm using simple pagination script. If the pages are 2 or 3 pages, it's just fine, when it goes to 6+. it gets funky.

/html

```
<div id='center'>
  <div class='pages_front'></div>
</div>
```

/css

```
.front {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 4px 5px 6px;
    margin: 3px 4px 5px 6px;
    height: 552px;
    width:850px;
}
.front li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 190px;
    padding: 3px 4px 5px 6px;
    background: #E6E6FA;
    border: 1px solid #999999; 
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3px 4px 5px 6px;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    height: 262px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
#center {
  display: block;
  margin:0 auto; 
  width:30%;
}
.pages_front {
    margin:0px;
    width: 800px;
    clear: both;
    display: inline;
}
.pages_front ul {

}
.pages_front ul li {
    float: none; 
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 3px;
}
.pages_front ul li a {
    padding: 3px 5px 2px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    color: #000;
}
.pages_front ul li.on a {
    background: #CCCCCC;
    color: #104E8B;
}
.pages_front ul li span span  {
    margin:0px;
    color: #bfbfbf;
    padding: 3px 5px 2px;
    background: #eeeeee;
}
```

examples:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the #center width, try to change it to other, maybie pixelated value.

Comment: that width is not the problem. the problem is as the pages increase the size of the width dynamically changes as it detects more pages. so the entire entity needs to be always centered, but I don't know enough about css to know exactly how to do that.

Comment: also you should use the add comment for this kind of suggestion I think.